# Add multiple objects into one object

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

How can I add multiple objects into one object? I have a selectbox change event that has a handler like this:

```
this.selectBoxChanges = {};

onSelect: function(event){
    var p = $(event.currentTarget).attr('id');
    var obj = {};
    obj[p] = $(event.currentTarget).val();
    this.selectBoxChanges = obj;
},
```

What I wanted to do is store all my objects in an object called `selectBoxChanges` so that when a confirm button is selected all the objects will be passed to a backbone model. Like this:

```
onConfirm: function(){
    this.model.set(this.selectBoxChanges);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer was simple didn't see it until I had posted the thread all I had to do was

```
this.selectBoxChanges = {};

onSelect: function(event){
    var p = $(event.currentTarget).attr('id');
    this.selectBoxChanges[p] = $(event.currentTarget).val();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Ha, you posted the answer below before I could submit this one. I'm going to leave it hear anyway :)

original post -->

are you trying to store multiple form elements in the object, or are you trying to store multiple values from the same list box in object?

you can add properties to selectBoxChanges the same way you're currently adding them to your obj object:

```
selectBoxChange[this.id] = $(this).val();
```

however, if you're trying to do this for the same object repeatedly you would need to be able to use something other than the element id that would be able to be used by backbone.

if you wanted to append all of the different items a user selected from the drop down you could store an array of items:

```
if(selectBoxChange[this.id]) {
  selectBoxChange[this.id].push($(this).val());
} else {
  selectBoxChange[this.id] = [$(this).val()];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You assign properties to objects. A property can be a variable, a function, another object, another property, etc.

```
var selectBoxChanges = {
    "values" : {
        "oldValue" : oldVal,
        "newValue" : newVal
    },
    "anotherProperty": someVariable,
    "functionProperty": function () {
       // do stuff
    }
};
```